# Output AC coupling: upper limit or lower limit?

Tags: ac, capacitance, high-pass-filter, coupling

I bought a DC2900A board for my project.

In its datasheet it is stated:

> The maximum repetition rate of the pulsed laser should be 100kHz. The DC2900A repetition rate is limited by the output AC coupling capacitor and assumes a pulse width of 5ns.

I was questioning why is that so, since LTC6561 chip is 220 MHz amplifier. In my mind 100 kHz should be nothing to this chip. Even APD has 2ns rise time.

Then I emailed about my question to them asking: Why AC coupling capacitor should ever limit the repetition rate, since it acts like a high-pass filter?

I got this response:

> The DC2900A upper limit on repetition rate of 100kHz is stated due to the output AC coupling cap (C1, 100pF) used. There will be a slow tail due to AC coupling the output as shown in this slide related to LTC6560.

> At 400ns/div, you’ll have 3 divisions (1.2us, LHS waveform) before the waveform settles at the load with a coupling cap of 1nF.

> With a 100pF cap, you’d expect this to be faster.

> But, that’s the reason that the demo manual states that the repetition rate should not be too high to allow for proper settling before the next pulse comes in.

So, does anybody know why this capacitor is limiting, or am I missing out on basic theory?

[image: DC2900a board].

Comment: [Demo Manual DC2900A](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/evaluation-hardware-and-software/evaluation-boards-kits/dc2900a.html) _"The output is AC-coupled with a **1000pF** capacitor (C1)"_. so the manual appears to be incorrect. Perhaps C1 was 1000pF but was changed to 100pF to allow a faster repetition rate? Or perhaps it's just plain wrong. Please show us the slide with the 'slow tail'.

Comment: I am confused how to add image directly to reply. But this seems work. https://i.ibb.co/Lh0DnyL/LTC6560.jpg

Comment: Even if they put any capacitor, it should act like bottom limit to repetition rate, right? Since ac coupled output blocks low rates.

Comment: Perhaps the 100pF max has to do with the ESR and SRF at >=1GHz for most caps